# how to display textbox by clicking button in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

We are required to use jsp for the Position dropdown, My problem is on how to show/hide a textbox if button  is clicked?if i type 3 letters in textbox i want to show all  Physician related to that names.can anyone provide me some suggestions using jsp?
I dont know how to do.

Comment: Have a look at some kind of jQuery auto-suggest field. For this you'll need a server side method that accepts a string, searches the database and returns a Json result that contains any results matching the string. See maybe https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: thank you,bt i want to know how to display textbox by clicking button

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showTextArea').click(function(){
        $('#myTextArea').show();
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" value="Show TextArea" id="showTextArea">

<textarea id="myTextArea" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh you little rascal, you have two questions in one.

### How to show textarea onclick

```css
input{
  display: none;
}
span{
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  padding: 5px;
}
input:not(:checked) + textarea{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Add</span>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <textarea>Foobar</textarea>
</label>
```

### How to make suggestions

Because the informations about the physicans you gave is cheap, i will answer it after you show use "what do you have, how far you came".

Comment: thank you.if i click outside the add button the textbox remains invisible....is this possible

Comment: what? please check your sentence again.